# glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 0 and no error in glGetError

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, sdl, framebuffer

glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 0 and there is no error returned from glGetError afterwards. Is it safe to assume that this is a driver bug? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation for OpenGL in how to handle this situation.

I am writing a game using SDL2 on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) with the nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: I would assume the SDL error handling internally invokes glGetError and thus catches it away from you. Try SDL_GetError() http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError instead.

Comment: but glCheckFramebufferStatus is a direct call to the OpenGL API. How can SDL intercept that?

Comment: Have you tried with SDL_GetError?

Comment: yes. It returns an empty string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone wants to know, it turns out I was running glCheckFramebufferStatus when no framebuffer was bound.

Answer (score 4):

check if you forgot to set your context as the current context. that's my case.

Answer (score 1):

GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if target is not GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER or GL_FRAMEBUFFER. So you may check if your target is of one of those types.

Comment: I got this from here [OpenGl.org](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml)

> "Additionally, if an error occurs, zero is returned."

And only in case target is not GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER or GL_FRAMEBUFFER.

> "GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated"

So i guess, an error occurs, but they wont tell you which one indeed.

Comment: What is supposed to generate GL_INVALID_ENUM? glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 0 and glGetError returns GL_No_ERROR? Are you saying GL_INVALID_ENUM is 0?